# Como mostrar data e hora no php

Tags: php

Como faço para mostrar a data e hora após o usuário enviar um recado?

Criei no banco de dados uma coluna chamada 'data' do tipo 'DATETIME'.

No php usei o seguinte código para inserir os dados:

`Inserir.php`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO autoriza (ID, data) VALUES( '$id', 'NOW()')";
$acao_sql = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

`Lista.php`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM autoriza ORDER BY ID DESC";
$acao_sql = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($lista = $acao_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       echo "Recado enviado em: ".$lista['data']; 
}
```

O resultado acima mostra: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: Consegui usando o seguinte código: date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$mysqldata = new DateTime();
$data = $mysqldata->format(DateTime::ISO8601);$sql = "INSERT INTO autoriza (ID, data, nome, cpf) VALUES( '$id', '$data', '$nome', '$cpf')";
$acao_sql = $mysqli->query($sql);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize sem as apas na função [`NOW()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) e coloque `id` com [`auto_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) na sua tabela:

`Inserir.php`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO autoriza (data) VALUES(NOW())";
$acao_sql = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

*Ele não está gravando um [**datetime**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) corretamente por causa das aspas simples ...*

---

Para formatar um [**datetime**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) use a função [**date_format**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), como demostrado abaixo.

`Lista.php`

```
$sql = "SELECT date_format(data, '%d/%m/%Y') as data FROM autoriza ORDER BY ID DESC";
$acao_sql = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($lista = $acao_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       echo "Recado enviado em: ".$lista['data']; 
}
```

***Referências***

- [3.6.9 Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)
- [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)
- [12.7 Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
- [11.3.1 The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Agradecido! Funcionou! Agora preciso colocar na ordem certa a data DIA - MES - ANO. Vou pesquisar por aqui.

Comment: Consgeui formatar a data assim: <?php $data =  date_create($lista['data']);
   echo date_format($data, 'd-m-Y H:i:s'); ?>

Comment: @GustavoCave, alterei a resposta adicionando como poderia trabalhar com datas para apresentação de resultados ...

Answer (score 0):

Tem a função `date()` nativo do php.

Mais informação:
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.datetime.php

Para cadastrar `id` você pode usar o `PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT`

Mais informação:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

```
<?php
$data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //formato 2014-05-04 18:00:00
$sql = "INSERT INTO autoriza (data) VALUES('".data."')"; 
$acao_sql = $mysqli->query($sql);

//mostra
$sql = "SELECT * FROM autoriza ORDER BY ID DESC"; 
$acao_sql = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($lista = $acao_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
 echo $lista['data'];
}
?>
```